# Ruby scope on main

Tags: ruby

I would like to understand why this code does not work:

```
array = [1,2,3]

def display_size()
    puts "self from method: #{self}"
    puts "Size from method: #{array.size}"
end

puts "self from main: #{self}"
puts "Size from main: #{array.size}"
display_size()
```

The output with the error:

```
$ ruby scope.rb 
self from main: main
Size from main: 3
self from method: main
scope.rb:5:in `display_size': undefined local variable or method `array' for main:Object (NameError)
    from scope.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I surmise that this is a scoping issue. I guess this means that there is a new scope in the method, where `array` is not visible.

Initially I expected the variable to be in the same scope as the method as they are both defined on main...

Comment: Because method is not lambda and it does not behave as a closure. Imagine you are calling this method from outside of this file: there will not be any `array` variable defined.

Comment: @mudasobwa why didn't you add this as an answer?

Comment: Because this is a quick sidenote. All the answers below are better, than this remark.

Comment: @mudasobwa well this point helped me a lot "Imagine you are calling this method from outside of this file", so thanks for that

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is a scoping issue. If you want `array` to be accessible inside that method change it to `@array`

```
@array = [1,2,3]

def display_size()
    puts "self from method: #{self}"
    puts "Size from method: #{@array.size}"
end

puts "self from main: #{self}"
puts "Size from main: #{@array.size}"
display_size()
```

`array` is a local variable and is only scoped locally.

`@array` is an instance variable and is available everywhere within the same class.

If you want to avoid creating an instance variable, you will need to pass the array to your method instead.

```
array = [1,2,3]

def display_size(array)
    puts "self from method: #{self}"
    puts "Size from method: #{array.size}"
end

puts "self from main: #{self}"
puts "Size from main: #{array.size}"
display_size(array)
```

Comment: Upvote for demonstrating that you can use instance variables outside of a class definition! I wish you had explained how that works...

Comment: @AndyJones Upvotes are not for encouraging answerers, they are for marking a value of this particular answer to this particular question. “Outside of class” is a nonsense in ruby, there is no “outside of class” anywhere. Here they are defined inside a special `Object` instance, as known as `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that your code is the body of a method being executed:

```
class MyClass
  def inspect
    'my_main'
  end

  def to_s
    inspect
  end

  def foo
    array = [1,2,3]

    def display_size
      puts "self from method: #{self}"
      puts "Size from method: #{array.size}"
    end

    puts "self from main: #{self}"
    puts "Size from main: #{array.size}"
    display_size
  end
end

my_main = MyClass.new
my_main.foo
```

The output is almost identical:

```
self from main: my_main
Size from main: 3
self from method: my_main
scope.rb:15:in `display_size': undefined local variable or method `array' for my_main:MyClass (NameError)
    from scope.rb:20:in `foo'
    from scope.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

The `def display_size` line in `foo` creates a new instance method. Since there are no "nested methods" in Ruby, it's equivalent to:

```
class MyClass
  def display_size()
    puts "self from method: #{self}"
    puts "Size from method: #{array.size}"
  end

  def foo
    array = [1,2,3]

    puts "self from main: #{self}"
    puts "Size from main: #{array.size}"
    display_size()
  end
end
```

I think it's obvious that `array` is not accessible from within `display_size`.

Comment: IMO if you give Ruby examples they should be runnable. (You can't define a method inside a method.)

Comment: @AndyJones I don't understand your comment. Do you have problems running my example? (And yes, you can define a method from within a method)

Comment: apologies, you are quite right.  That's very interesting.  I really thought that that didn't work!  (And of course your example is *supposed* to give an error.)

Answer (score 2):

Variables starting with lowercase letters are local variables. They are called local variables because they are local to the scope they are defined in.

You have two scopes in your example: the script scope of whatever file that code is in and the method scope of `display_size`. The local variable `array` in the script scope and the local variable `array` in the method scope are two different local variables. (And the latter one doesn't actually exist which is why you are seeing the error.) That's the whole point of scopes and local variables, that you can re-use the names of local variables in different parts of your code.

Just imagine what would happen if that were *not* the case: then every Ruby programmer on the whole planet would have to agree with every other Ruby programmer on the whole planet on what to name their local variables. If I have a local variable named `address` in my code, then nobody else in the entire world can use that name as the name of a local variable!

There are several ways to solve this.

The first way is to use nested scopes. In Ruby, there is exactly one construct which created a nested scope: a block. (Well, and a lambda literal, but I will consider those to be the same.)

So, you could either use a lambda literal instead of a method:

```
display_size = -> {
  puts "self from lambda: #{self}"
  puts "Size from lambda: #{array.size}"
}

display_size.()
# self from lambda: main
# Size from lambda: 3
```

or, if you want to use a method, then you need to create the method using a block. Thankfully, there is just such a method which creates a method from a block: `Module#define_method`:

```
define_method(:display_size) do
  puts "self from method: #{self}"
  puts "Size from method: #{array.size}"
end

display_size
# self from method: main
# Size from method: 3
```

Another way would be to pass the array as an argument to the method; parameter bindings become local variables in the method body:

```
def display_size(array)
  puts "self from method: #{self}"
  puts "Size from method: #{array.size}"
end

display_size(array)
# self from method: main
# Size from method: 3
```

(Note how we now have two different local variables `array` in two different scopes.)

And a third way would be to use instance variables, class variables, global variables, or constants instead of local variables:

```
def display_size
  puts "self from method: #{self}"
  puts "Size from method: #{@array.size}"
end

@array = [1, 2, 3]

display_size
# self from method: main
# Size from method: 3

def display_size
  puts "self from method: #{self}"
  puts "Size from method: #{@@array.size}"
end

@@array = [1, 2, 3]

display_size
# self from method: main
# Size from method: 3

def display_size
  puts "self from method: #{self}"
  puts "Size from method: #{$array.size}"
end

$array = [1, 2, 3]

display_size
# self from method: main
# Size from method: 3

def display_size
  puts "self from method: #{self}"
  puts "Size from method: #{Ary.size}"
end

Ary = [1, 2, 3]

display_size
# self from method: main
# Size from method: 3
```

(Note how I used `Ary` instead of `Array` in the last example? Again, that's because there already is a constant named `Array` defined in the scope.)